# Does wildcard search slow down Splunk results search?

Tags: search, optimization, splunk

I use Splunk Enterprise and try to optimize my query so I write

(1)
    *index = "main" AND host = "*prod" source = "/sys/logs/myApplication.log" AND httpStatus = 201*

(2)
    *index = "main" AND host = "com.myorganization.london.prod" source = "/sys/logs/myApplication.log" AND httpStatus = 201*

We have only one prod instance on which there is myApplication.log so source-host conjunction gives one result but have over
100 prod hosts. Which is better approach (1) or (2).  And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More specific searches are better than less specific ones.  See for yourself by running both and comparing the info in the Job Inspector.